# I'm getting an error in the Unity Editor saying that I have multiple plugins. How can I fix this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, sdk

So, I have decided to use Agora for my multiplayer voice chat feature in my FPS Game. I have been getting this error recently in the Unity Editor saying that there are multiple plugins as seen in the screenshot provided. How can I get rid of this error?

[The Error I'm Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/573L8.png)

Comment: Select each dll in the inspector and set their platform settings correctly. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing it through the package manager, then reinstall agora through package manager.

It seems somehow the existing agora is not properly imported & the only way was to remove the other package from the package manager. That way the existing package remains untouched and unity will stop complaining about duplicate plugins.

These people had the anae problems:

- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1541473/how-can-i-fix-multiple-plugins-with-the-same-name.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I had a follow-up question. If I remove the package manually, will it not fix the problem when I reimport?

Comment: @Pratyush As long as you remove everything associated with it, it should work